# Detecting out-of-view flex controls

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml

In my flex app I have custom tooltips on buttons that hide and show based on user context.
The problem that I dealing with is that when I call my showTips() function I only want to show tooltips on the buttons that visible in the view. So buttons that on a un-selected tab (tabNavigator) should not show the tooltips.
For some reason all tooltips are showing.
Is there a way to detect if a button is not in current view, like on a un-selected tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you gave us some code I could check this out, but would this work?

```
if(button.parent.visible) { showTip(button);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of custom coding for each button, make use your tabnavigator's creation policy is set to "auto".

Check this link for more details

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=layoutperformance_05.html

Comment: Well, since I am using faBridge, I nned the creationPolicy="all".
But what I am looking for is something in the displayList (maybe) that tells me if the button instance is in user's current view.